# Android Volley: Cannot resolve symbol Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to use Volley to send requests from my Android app.

I have included this in the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
   compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

I want to use:

```
requestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

But neither `requestQueue` nor `Volley` can be resolved.

I have tried:

```
import com.android.volley;
```

But it also says that volley can't be resolved. I have done a gradle sync.

I have not downloaded anything. My understanding is that adding Volley to build.gradle takes the place of actually downloading the library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct import is `import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;` (you can check the code [here](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/Volley.java)), and `this` has to be a `Context` object

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This will also help me with the other import statements that I need.

Comment: Do you know how to import StringRequest needed in Google's example: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Comment: `import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;`

Comment: I found I had to restart Android Studio after adding it to the dependencies in the gradle file. Nothing else worked until I restarted.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Blackbelt's answer, I was able to import the following for Google's standard example https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
```

The *this* in

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

became

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
```

also thanks to Blackbelt's answer. I had to play around with where I could call `getContext()` for my code. I ended up checking if the queue has already been instantiated inside my first request and set it if it hasn't.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem today. Following works for me:

In Android Studio: `Build -> Clean Project`, and then `Build -> Rebuild Project`